# What is the ios text notification that disappears after a couple of seconds

Tags: ios

On Instagram, after I tweet a photo, there will be a little text box in the middle of the screen saying "Tweet posted" as shown in the following picture. It disappears after like a second or two. What exactly is it? How can I build something like that in IOS? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I would think it's just a UIView with some text inserted that's controlled programatically, not a standard control.

Comment: I hope it's a standard control in IOS. It would save some work. Anyone knows about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed a standard control. it's called [UILabel](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html).

```
NSString *text = @"Tweet posted";
UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0f];
CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(320, 100)];

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width + 20, size.height + 20)];
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
label.backgroundColor = [[UIColor darkGrayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.8];
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
label.font = font;
label.text = text;
label.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
label.shadowColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

label.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2, self.view.bounds.size.height/2);

[self.view addSubview:label];

double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
        label.alpha = 0.0f;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [label removeFromSuperview];
    }];
});
```

Nothing fancy, just standard properties and some layer "magic". And GCD.
Code should be self-explanatory. Don't forget to `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

Comment: Hey Matthias, thanks for the answer. I know we can build this with UILabel. I'm just wondering if there is anything standard in IOS that can do all of these styling and animation for me.

Comment: how more standard than a UILabel can it be? This is already everything you need. But I'm sure some guy made an "I do everything you want"-Cocoapods-Thingie for this which uses like 1000 lines of code.

Comment: I read through http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW41 and didn't find anything. So I'll accept your code. Thanks!